# Quicktime for windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, quicktime, 64-bit

I am using windows 7 64 bit on hp probook 4520s and want to install quicktime, apple provided link give the quicktime to download and install but it give error of some assembly instruction. I think that version of quick time is for 32 bit, microsoft have also given the same url for isntalling quicktime on windows 7 64 bit on its website so can some one please tell me from where I can get 64 bit version and solve my problem.

thanks in advance guys-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicktime is a part of the iTunes install, so if you download the [64 bit version of iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1047), you will get it as a package deal.

You should probably try uninstalling all apple components first if you are getting error codes on installing.

Could you also paste those error codes for further troubleshooting?